# Issue with PHP Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, preg-match

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project, and I'm making a custom validation, and I'm no regex expert.
So far, I have made a simple test, but I cannot seem to get this right.
This validation can only contain A-Z a-z 0-9 and special characters such as:

```
@ ! # / $ % & ' * + - = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~ .
```

I cannot have `( ) [ ] : ; " < > , \`

in my controller:

```
public function test(){

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('communication_number', 'Communication Number', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_communication_number');

    $this->form_validation->set_message("validate_communication_number", "The %s field must only contain blah blah");

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Passed";
    }
}

public function validate_communication_number($communication_number)
{
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9@\!\#\/$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?/^/_/`/{/|/}/~/.]+$/i", $communication_number))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an example string that doesn't work correctly?

Comment: possibly will help you in the future: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @DavidYue Thanks! I will keep that bookmarked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape backslashes using `\\` if you use double quotes or just change to single quote like this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9@\!\#\/$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?/^/_/`/{/|/}/~/.]+$/i', $ff_communication_room))
              ^--- Here
```

However, you can write your regex as this (you don't need all those escaped backslashes:

```
^[a-z0-9@!#\/$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~.-]+$
```

As you can see, it's a valid regex:
[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL2yR1/1)**

Code

```
$re = '/^[a-z0-9@!#\/$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~.-]+$/i'; // Note hyphen at the end
$str = "your string"; 

if(preg_match($re, $str))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fede!!! I tested every single special character, and it worked like a charm. The reason I have a double quote instead of a single quote is because I needed the single quote in the regex. Unfortunately, I cannot give you a vote up, but when I have enough points, I will come back and give you my vote just like I promise the others who helped me before.

Comment: well, look at that. I have enough points to give you my vote! Once again, thanks!